# How should I build this LSTM model in Pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

On Pytorch, if you want to build a model like this, ⇓[image: normal bi-LSTM]
the code will be:

```py
import torch.nn as nn

BLSTM = nn.LSTM(3, 3, bidirectional=True) # input and hidden sizes are example. it doesn't have to be 3.
```

---

But I want to build a model like this. ⇓[image: I don't know]
This model has two-layerd forward & backward LSTM.

***My question is how to build this model in Pytorch.***

---

The code I can think of is this:

```py
import torch.nn

BLSTM = nn.LSTM(3, 3, 2, bidirectional=True) # input and hidden sizes are example. it doesn't have to be 3.
```

I thought it's wrong because this ⇓ would be the model if I used this code.
[image: cat]
I feel that this model is a little different from the model I want to build.

Comment: That looks correct to me. `nn.LSTM(input_size=3, hidden_size=3, num_layers=2, bidirectional=True)`. What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: thank you for your comment.
I think that will not work because the model will be different from the model I want to build.
I editted the question to explain my thought. If you have time, I want to know whether I'm right or not.